# Why node export:import link is not displayed?

Tags: importing-exporting

I want to export drupal 7 nodes with node export. I have downloaded and enabled the node export module. The node export option has been added in the content tabs next to view,edit,translate.
I exporte the nodes in a file however I cannot find the import link in order to import them!
Is there something else to configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `node/add/node_export` (Content > add content > Node export: import) and paste the code or load from file.

Comment: When I go to Content > add content there is no Node export: import link available. I also tried the following. I wrote in the url the path localocost.../node/add/node_export and it throws the error "You are not authorized to access this page. ". Ho do I authorize my self to do this?

Comment: I went to People>Permissions and I have selected  Export nodes, import nodes for the administrator(me).Nothing changed however...

Comment: @user21321 maybe you just found a bug in module. Consider posting in module's issue queue.

Comment: @Molot, Thanks... Too bad, it seems a nice feature..

Comment: @user21321 and probably something that can be fixed. Both Bala and larrydahooster told you the same, and I remember it to be that way, too, so if it simply does not work for you, DO open a bugreport! Probably that's just a minor conflict with something on your system and module's authors will be able to guide you and to solve it with you.

Comment: I tried it with an clean install and works perfect! There is a hook in node_export's node_export_access_import() function, that allows to alter the 'node_export_access_import' persmission. Maybe there is a module that interferes with node_export?

Comment: I will also try it with a clean install and I'll let you know..

Comment: Problem found. I found it using the information @larrydahooster provided. There was another module that blocked the node import functionality. Thanks to all of you for your prompt response!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `node/add/node_export` and then select the Import tab, Paste the exported code and then select the **content type** you want to import from the list.

> For **advanced imports** if you are familiar with the Feeds module, enable
>         Node export feeds module to use with the Feeds import interface 
>         http://drupal.org/project/feeds

Comment: When I go to Content > add content there is no Node export: import link available. I also tried the following. I wrote in the url the path localocost.../node/add/node_export and it throws the error "You are not authorized to access this page. ". Ho do I authorize my self to do this?  
I went to People>Permissions and I have selected Export nodes, import nodes for the administrator(me).Nothing changed however...